# Property 'unlisten' does not exist on type 'component'

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to scroll to top of the page after route changes. I will use `react-router`'s `history.listen` hook. However, it says `Property 'unlisten' does not exist on type 'ScrollToTop'.`

It doesn't seem like a complicated problem but I could not figure out what wrong is. Please do not suggest another method, instead explain a solution for this error. I just want to eliminate this error.

This is the code piece I use

```
import {RouteComponentProps, withRouter} from "react-router-dom";

type TScrollToTopProps = RouteComponentProps;

class ScrollToTop extends Component<TScrollToTopProps> {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.unlisten = this.props.history.listen((location) => {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unlisten();
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.children;
  }
}

export default withRouter(ScrollToTop);
```

Comment: `unlisten` does not exist in the class. You could just declare it and will be available on the `this` context

Answer (score 0):

You should just create a state `unlisten` like this

```
import { RouteComponentProps, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { UnregisterCallback } from 'history';

interface IScrollToTopState {
  unlisten: UnregisterCallback;
}
class ScrollToTop extends Component<RouteComponentProps, IScrollToTopState> {
  state: IScrollToTopState = {
    unlisten: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      unlisten: this.props.history.listen((location) => {
         window.scrollTo(0, 0);
      })
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.state.unlisten();
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.children;
  }
}

export default withRouter(ScrollToTop);
```